# how to get the latest record of loginevent from each user?

Tags: mysql, sql

This question may already asked, but my question refers to two separate tables. I have only seen the answer when using same table with date row on it.
I have two tables, one is the user table and the other is login_log table.
I want to get the event from latest date record and from each user.
I have already made sql query, but cant understand how can I pick the max(date) from separate user.

```
SELECT s.username_id,s.date,s.event,m.username
FROM sys_log s join
     users m
     on s.username_id = m.id

id, username
---------
1 test
2 test2

id, username_id,    date,           event
------------------------------------------
1       1     1/1/2017 22:10:11     logout
2       1    1/1/2017  22:09:11     login
3       2      1/1/2017 21:05:11    logout
4       2     1/1/2017 21:02:11     login
```

the output should be like this

```
id, username, event ,date
-------------------------
1    test     logout  xxx
2    test2    logout  xxx
```

Comment: You have a query, two result sets, and no explanation of the data.  I'm confused.

Comment: @Somepub do you want latest login per user?

Comment: @YossiVainshtein You are correct. Sorry for little confusion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
select s.username_id, s.date, s.event, m.username
from sys_log s join
     users m
     on s.sys_auth_id = m.id
where s.date = (select max(s2.date) from sys_log s2 where s2.sys_auth_id = s.sys_auth_id);
```

Comment: Thank you for understanding me! I can see now how this query logic works